# searches incoming gmail mails for specific keywords

Tags: gmail

Can Gmail be set up to search incoming mail, on my android phone, for specific keywords?

Then when a keyword is detected, alert the user with a particular sound?

Iv'e looked through all the gmail settings, but cannot find a way of achieving this, if it's at all possible, that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gmail app  for android has a filter that if set up with your gmail labels filter correctly,  Will produce a sound of your choice on certain keywords.